# pandas new column if statement

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

I have a data frame for which I would like to add a column value using an if statement. I have been trying a lambda function but have not had luck. I want to add a column that says if threshold< order, then set new column to threshold else set column to order.

```
df_new

  Order       Threshold  
 20,000        100,000
 500,000       50,000
 100,000       75,000
```

I tried:

```
 df_new['New Column'].apply(lambda x: df_new['Threshold'] if < df_new['Order'] else df_new['Order Quantity'])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes it is helpful to use an algorithm which avoids `if` / `else` constructs. The below solution is likely more efficient and, moreover, adds some intuitive logic.

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Order': [20000, 500000, 100000],
                   'Threshold': [100000, 50000, 75000]})

df['New'] = np.minimum(df['Threshold'], df['Order'])

#     Order  Threshold    New
# 0   20000     100000  20000
# 1  500000      50000  50000
# 2  100000      75000  75000
```